# Problems with FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

Hello I'm trying to pass a intent to a FragmentActivity but it's not working. The activity close in the initialization of the FragmentActivity. Here is the Activity:

```
public class ProcuraPontoActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener {
    /** EditText da procura do ponto. Geralmente o input é o ID ou nome do ponto */
    private EditText procura;
    /** ListView que mostra todos os pontos encontrados */
    private ListView lv;
    /** DAO do Ponto para procurar pontos */
    private PontoDAO dao;
    /** ArrayList de Pontos encontrados */
    private ArrayList<Ponto> AL = null;
    /** ArrayList que vai pegar a ID do ponto encontrado com o nome do Ponto para mostrar na lv */
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> lista;
    /** Adaptador utilizado */
    private SimpleAdapter adapter;
    /** O usuário atual */
    private Usuario user;

    /**
     * Inicia a activity de procura de pontos.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.procura_ponto);
        lista = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        AL = new ArrayList<Ponto>();
        user = Usuario.toUser(getIntent().getBundleExtra("user"));

        /*
         * Widgets
         */

        procura = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.procura_ponto_et);
        Button achar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.procura_ponto_achar);
        TextView ppSigla = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ppSigla);
        ppSigla.setText(user.getSigla());
        achar.setOnClickListener(this);
        dao = new PontoDAO(this);

        /*
         * ListView
         */
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.procura_ponto_lv);
        String[] from = new String[] { "a", "b"};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.pp_tv1, R.id.pp_tv2 };
        int layout = R.layout.procura_ponto_list;
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this ,lista, layout, from, to);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    /**
     * Faz a verificação da procura e exibe resultados.
     */
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!(procura.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
            lista.clear();
            FiltroPonto fp = new FiltroPonto();
            fp.setNomePonto(procura.getText().toString());
            fp.setValor(1);
            AL = dao.procuraPonto(user.getSigla(),fp);
            Log.i("ProcuraPontoActivity",
                    "Número de pontos encontrados: " + AL.size());
            for (Ponto p : AL) {
                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                if (p.getIdPonto().equals(null)) {
                    hm.put("a", user.getSigla()+p.getPontoNome());
                } else {
                    hm.put("a", p.getIdPonto());
                }
                hm.put("b",
                        "[UTM] E: [" + p.getUTMEste() + "] N: ["
                                + p.getUTMNorte() + "] Fuso: ["
                                + p.getUTMFuso() + "]");
                lista.add(hm);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Método chamado cada vez que um click é feito na listview percorrida
     * que vai chamar uma nova intent para iniciar o Ponto (PontoTabActivity)
     */
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        PontoDAO pdao = new PontoDAO(this);
        String max = pdao.maxIdPonto(user.getIdUsuario(), user.getSigla());
        if (AL.get(arg2).getIdPonto().equals(max)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, PontoTabActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("id", AL.get(arg2).getIdPonto());
            i.putExtra("user", getIntent().getBundleExtra("user"));
            i.putExtra("cria", 1);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        } else {
            Intent i2 = new Intent(this, RelatorioPontos.class);
            i2.putExtra("id", AL.get(arg2).getIdPonto());
            startActivity(i2);
        }

    }
}
```

And this is the RelatorioPontos.class:

```
public class RelatorioPontos extends FragmentActivity implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {

    private TabHost mTabHost;
    private HashMap mapTabInfo = new HashMap();
    private TabInfo mLastTab = null;

    private class TabInfo {
        private String tag;
        private Class clss;
        private Bundle args;
        private Fragment fragment;
        TabInfo(String tag, Class clazz, Bundle args) {
            this.tag = tag;
            this.clss = clazz;
            this.args = args;
        }
    }

    class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

        private final Context mContext;

        /** 
         * @param context 
         */
        public TabFactory(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            return v;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.relatorio_layout);

        initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
        }
    }   

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); //salva a tabela selecionada
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
        String id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
        args.putString("id", id);
        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
        TabInfo tabInfo = null;
        RelatorioPontos.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Dados").setIndicator("Dados"),
                (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Dados", DadosPonto.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        RelatorioPontos.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Analises").setIndicator("Analises"),
                (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Analises", AnalisesPonto.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        RelatorioPontos.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Multimidia").setIndicator("Multimidia"),
                (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Multimidia", ArquivosMultimidia.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    }

    /** 
     * @param activity
     * @param tabHost
     * @param tabSpec
     * @param clss
     * @param args 
     */
    private static void addTab(RelatorioPontos activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
        tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
        String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

        tabInfo.fragment = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (tabInfo.fragment != null && !tabInfo.fragment.isDetached()) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(tabInfo.fragment);
            ft.commit();
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }

        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }

    public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
        TabInfo newTab = (TabInfo) this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
        if (mLastTab != newTab) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            if (mLastTab != null) {
                if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                    ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
                }
            }
            if (newTab != null) {
                if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                    newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                    ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
                } else {
                    ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
                }
            }

            mLastTab = newTab;
            ft.commit();
            this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the LogCat:

```
06-06 11:45:20.661: E/AndroidRuntime(905): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{caderneta.main.activity/caderneta.main.activity.RelatorioPontos}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 11:45:20.661: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-06 11:45:20.661: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-06 11:45:20.661: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-06 11:45:20.661: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-06 11:45:20.661: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-06 11:45:20.661: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-06 11:45:20.661: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-06 11:45:20.661: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 11:45:20.661: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-06 11:45:20.661: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-06 11:45:20.661: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-06 11:45:20.661: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-06 11:45:20.661: E/AndroidRuntime(905): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 11:45:20.661: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at caderneta.main.activity.RelatorioPontos.initialiseTabHost(RelatorioPontos.java:74)
06-06 11:45:20.661: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at caderneta.main.activity.RelatorioPontos.onCreate(RelatorioPontos.java:61)
06-06 11:45:20.661: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-06 11:45:20.661: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-06 11:45:20.661: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-06 11:45:20.661: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Check getIntent().getBundleExtra("user") is NULL or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple: RelatorioPontos#initialise... Parameter args is null! When you first create the Activity then the bundle savedInstanceState is null. When the activity recreates to whatever reason (configuration change or you go back to it), then savedInstance will not be null.

**Edit** (based on below comments): 
I don't have a clear understading on what your code is supposed to do (that is your responsibility) and it is not constructive; but I would remove that paramater.

Based on the current implementation something close to working would be:

```
private void initialiseTabHost() {
        String id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("id", id);
        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
        TabInfo tabInfo = null;
        RelatorioPontos.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Dados").setIndicator("Dados"),
                (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Dados", DadosPonto.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        RelatorioPontos.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Analises").setIndicator("Analises"),
                (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Analises", AnalisesPonto.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        RelatorioPontos.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Multimidia").setIndicator("Multimidia"),
                (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Multimidia", ArquivosMultimidia.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    }
```

Comment: Hum I see, but how can I fix it?

Comment: Only one more question: How I get that args on the the DadosPonto.class for example, I put getArguments().getString("id"); or another thing?

Comment: I guess getArguments().getString("id"); should be OK

Answer (score 2):

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at initialiseTabHost(RelatorioPontos.java:74) and onCreate(RelatorioPontos.java:61)`.

Try to debug your code you will get the idea where and what value are passing as `null`